# Is it possible to transform array of objectsID to object in mongoDB using arrayToObject?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have array like this :

```
"organizationIds" : [ 
       ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73136d"), 
       ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73139d"), 
       ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73138d")
   ]
```

I would like to this turn to object:

```
"organization":{
 "ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73136d")":{
owner: false
 },
 "ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73138d")":{
owner: false
 }
 "ObjectId("60373852f64bf2cc8c73138d")":{
owner: true
 }
}
```

I have tried using:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{$addFields:{organizationsPermissions:{$arrayToObject:"$organizationIds"}}},])
```

but I keep getting  `error"Unrecognised input type format for $arrayToObject: objectId"`.

Is there a way to reach my wanted result?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution using aggregation framework.

`$arrayToObject` works on array with formats like this:

`[ [ "item", "abc123"], [ "qty", 25 ] ]`

So first convert your `organizationIds` array into that format by using the pipeline below which uses `$map` which works exactly like array map function in Javascript. Also `ObjectId` cant be used as object key so converted it into string as well.

```
{
"$addFields": {
  "organizationIds": {
    $map: {
      input: "$organizationIds",
      as: "org",
      in: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              $toString: "$$org"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              owner: false
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
}
}
```

Now you can use `$arrayToObject`.

```
{
"$addFields": {
  "organizationIds": {
    "$arrayToObject": "$organizationIds"
  }
}
}
```

Working example here. https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y8PNyRn7elA

Comment: `db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{$addFields:{organizationsPermissions:{$arrayToObject:{$map:{
    "input":"$organizationIds",
    "as":"out",
    "in":{
    "k":{$toString:"$$out"},
    "v":{"owner":false}
}
    }}}}}
])`

I used code above to make it happen. Which way would be more optimal for usage?

Comment: This will work as well, I broke it down for simplicity. As for optimal I guess your solution would be more efficient as you are not transforming and saving two times.

Comment: Sadly we scrapped this data storage idea and went with another way. Yes your way worked too. Thanks for help